# What's the time-out value for the start-up of a Windows service

Tags: c++, windows, service, timeout

In order to debug a Windows service, written here in my company, the `main` function starts with:

```
Sleep(3000); // three seconds
```

This should allow me to do an "Attach to Process" while the service is starting up, but I seem to be too slow, so I decided to modify this value to 30,000 (thirty seconds).

However now, when starting up the service, I get following error message:

```
Prompt>net start <Service_Application>
The service is not responding to the control function.
```

What is the maximum value I can put there in order not to fall into such time-out?

Comment: Unhappy guess, 30 seconds is the there-is-something-wrong timeout that the service manager uses to generate this error.  Consider 29 seconds.

Comment: Why don't you start the service from within the debugger so you can debug it from the very beginning and don't have to rely on timeouts like this to attach to the process after it starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value by accessing the registry key at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control` key `ServicesPipeTimeout` .

If this value is not set, its default value is set to 30 s ( see  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-control-handler-function to learn more about it ).